# Book recommendations for reading A. Okounkov and A. Vershik's approach for complex irreducible representations of symmetric groups?

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory, book-recommendation

Does anybody have book recommendations for reading A. Okounkov and A. Vershik's approach for complex irreducible representations of symmetric groups?  Preferably, I am looking for a book that is intended for an undergraduate/first year graduate student who know basics of Representation theory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not aware of many books following the Okounkov-Vershik approach (which is a shame because it is way more enlightening, at least in some directions...). One option though is this book, [Representation Theory of the Symmetric Groups: The Okounkov-Vershik Approach, Character Formulas, and Partition Algebras](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521118174); you can tell by the title that it is exactly what you are looking for but I would warn you, it is not the easiest read...

The original [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0503040) is a bit dense to study but I guess that depends on your algebra background; these [notes](http://www.math.iitb.ac.in/~mks/notes/vershik_okounkov.pdf) will help you if you decide to study from there a bit.

Another place to have a look, if you have access to it, is the book [Graphs on Surfaces and their applications](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540002031); read the appendix (by Zagier) on representation theory. Many libraries provide online access to the book, and Zagier manages to explain in a couple of pages the gist of what is going on in the Okounkov approach. At least you'll have a sort of roadmap for what's coming (the introduction of the original paper might seem a bit off-putting for all of us who lack Okounkov's and Vershik's insight).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions !

Comment: Zagier's appendix (as most of his work) can be found on [his home page](http://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/) as [Applications of the representation theory of finite groups](http://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/tex/ApplRepTheoryFiniteGroups/fulltext.pdf)